# Como remover pastas de um diretório

Tags: cmd

Tenho um projecto em Delphi 2010 no qual utilizo para comprimir e criar backups o WinRAR, através do seguinte código eu consigo comprimir a seguinte pasta `teste3`:

```
AFile := 'C:\teste1\teste2\teste3';
LocateFile := 'C:\Users\Desktop\BACKUPS\'+ FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Now) +'.rar';
winexec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a '+ LocateFile +' "'+ AFile + '"')), SW_HIDE);
```

Mas o ficheiro comprimido não esta a aparecer como pretendia só com a pasta `teste3` deixo aqui o exemplo do que pretendo.

Este é o directório da pasta `teste3`:

> C:\teste1\teste2\teste3

Estrutura:

```
c:
  teste1
    teste2
      teste3
        exemplo1.txt
        exemplo2.txt
        exemplo3.txt
      ficheiro1.txt
    ficheiro1.txt
```

Quando comprimido dentro do `.rar` tenho:

```
ficheiro.rar
  teste1
    teste2
      teste3
        exemplo1.txt
        exemplo2.txt
        exemplo3.txt
```

O que pretendo:

```
ficheiro.rar
  teste3
    exemplo1.txt
    exemplo2.txt
    exemplo3.txt
```

Se alguém conseguir contribuir com alguma coisa agradeço.

Comment: veja isso http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2413
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/DirectoryOperations_(Delphi)

Comment: se calhar não me expliquei bem na questão, mas essas duas pastas tem ficheiros dentro delas, mas quando comprimo a pasta "teste3" que se encontra dentro dessas elas tambem são comprimidas coisa que não queria e sem ficheiros

Comment: já fiz um ajuste na minha questão para tentar ficar mais explicito o que necessito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a opção [`-ep1`](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/html/helpswep1.htm), assim a pasta base não será adicionada.

No teu código use assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AFile: string;
  LocateFile: string;
begin
  AFile := 'C:\teste1\teste2\teste3';
  LocateFile := 'C:\Users\Desktop\BACKUPS\'+ FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Now) +'.rar';

  winexec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" -ep1 a '+ LocateFile +' "'+ AFile + '"')), SW_HIDE);
end;
```

Para ignorar pastas vazias, use a opção [`-ed`](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/html/helpswed.htm).